# Trying to get or post data, it's show error like this, MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here I created a project to store employee information, in this project DB also successfully connected, but when I tried to retrieve or create a new record, it shows error like this,

I already changed the mongo network setting also,

[image]

> MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
> at Timeout.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Router = require("./routes");
const cors = require('cors');

const { error } = require("jquery");



const app = express();
   app.use(express.json());
   mongoose.set('strictQuery', false);
   mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://admin:admin1234@hhap-db.n8zxs62.mongodb.net/test',
   { useNewUrlParser: true, useFindAndModify: true,  useUnifiedTopology: true },
  function CheckDb(){
    if(error){
        console.log("Error");
    }
    else{
        console.log("DB Connected");
    }
  }
);

app.use(Router);
app.use(cors());

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server is running at port 3000");
});
```

**router.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const userModel = require("./model/userModel");

const app = express();


app.post("/user/create", async (request, response) => {
    const user = new userModel(request.body);
    try {
      await user.save();
      response.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).send(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
});

app.get("/user/getAll", async (request,response) => {
    const user = await userModel.find({});
    console.log(user);
    try {
      response.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
      response.status(500).send(error);
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

 
  module.exports = app;
```

**userModel.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const user = new mongoose.Schema({
  fName: { type: String, required: true, },
  lName: { type: String, required: true, },
  address: { type: String, required: false, },
  email: { type: String, required: true, },
  mobileNumber: { type: Number, default: 0, },
  password: { type: String, required: true, },
  isActive: { type: Boolean, required: true, },
  userType: { type: String, required: true, },
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", user);

module.exports = User;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Issue in `mongoose.connect`

Try this:

```js
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb+srv://admin:admin1234@hhap-db.n8zxs62.mongodb.net/test", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    keepAlive: true
  })
  .then(
    async() => {
      console.log("database connected")
    },
    (err) => {
      console.log(err, "Error")
    }
  )
```